# R Каким образом я могу импортировать корректно df thx!

Tags: r, импорт, data.frame

Пытаюсь импортировать дату(может быть иная, но структура сохранена) посредством read.csv, scan(просьба не предлагать к нему нужно привыкать), вся трудность заключается в том, что имеется формат

```
24 10 2016 10:00,98910,99060,98800,98900
24 10 2016 10:01,98900,99050,98900,98990
24 10 2016 10:02,98990,99000,98910,98920
24 10 2016 10:03,98910,98920,98860,98860
24 10 2016 10:04,98860,98880.98810,98840
```

read.csv("D:\r.csv",header=F,sep=",")
казалось бы приводит в должный вид, но при вызове [,1] отображается дата и время, чего быть не должно.

Итого Необходимо импортировать таким образом, что бы кол-во colnum=6 or [,seq(1,6,1)]

в голову методы никакие не лезут, в иных случая выручал sep
..есть идея чтения даты и отдельно всего остального, а далее влеплиивание cbind'ом, но данное кажется не логичным

Пожалуйста помогите Камрады!
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать пакет `lubridate` для сколь угодно сложных манипуляций с датами, но тут достаточно выполнить

```
a <- c("24 10 2016 10:00", "24 10 2016 10:00")
substr(a, 1, 10)
[1] "24 10 2016" "24 10 2016"
```

(работаем с простыми строками, дальше нужно сконвертировать в формат даты)

Для времени - аналогично.

UPD 
На этапе импортирования проблема не решается, но можно отредактировать файл с помощью sed или awk (все под Linux), добавив правильный разделитель в правильном месте.

Answer (score 0):

Файл данных **r.csv** в каталоге **D:/-DtFls/**

```
24 10 2016 10:00,98910,99060,98800,98900
24 10 2016 10:01,98900,99050,98900,98990
24 10 2016 10:02,98990,99000,98910,98920
24 10 2016 10:03,98910,98920,98860,98860
24 10 2016 10:04,98860,98880,98810,98840
```

Основная идея: из строки вырезаем значение дня, месяца, года  и преобразуем как  дату:
было **24 10 2016 10:00** стало **24 10 2016** и далее конвертируем в дату используем **as.Date**, результат: **2016-10-24**

```
# пакет dplyr используем для добавления новых столбцов
library(dplyr)  
fl <- "D:/-DtFls/r.csv"
df.temp <- read.csv(fl, head=FALSE, sep=",")

# Добавляем столбец ChrDt, вырезав из "24 10 2016 10:00" значение даты. 
# Результат:  24 10 2016
df.temp.dt <- mutate(df.temp, ChrDt = substr(V1, 1, 10))

# Добавляем столбец DtDt, преобразовав строку "24 10 2016" как дату.
# Результат: 2016-10-24 
df.temp.dt1 <- mutate(df.temp.dt,  DtDt= as.Date(df.temp.dt$ChrDt, "%d %m %Y"))
```